# Mercurial Introduction - BitBucket and 3rd Party Server Issue

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, webfaction

I have just started working on a web project that uses Mercurial version control system to a bitbucket account.

The web project is hosted on a 3rd party server - Webfaction.

I have followed all the Mercurial tutorials at [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tutorial)

The tutorials state that a repository should be made on the local pc and then changes made to the code in the repository on the local pc and then added, committed and pushed to the bitbucket account.

But my project is hosted on a server - WebFaction, so all the code changes should happen on the server, so I can see that the changes work.

I cannot find a reference to changing the code on the WebFaction server (only on the local pc) and then committing and pushing the code from the WebFaction server to the bitbucket account. I simply don't know how to do this (or even if it can be done!).

Can someone give me the steps and syntax (as much as possible) to do this? Could you also keep the answers as simple as possible as there are huge parts of Mercurial I don't yet understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have full SSH access to the WebFaction server (you should according to the [WebFaction features page](https://www.webfaction.com/features)), I suggest you try following the detailled instructions found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678). If you get stuck on any step, then you can ask a more specific question (probably better to ask on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) though).

The fact that the repository is on a remote server does not really change anything. You connect through SSH to the remote server (WebFaction) and you follow the steps as if it was a local machine.